# How to make a dynamic body static in Cocos2d v3.0 with Chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, callback, game-physics, chipmunk

I’m using Cocos2d v3 and want to change a body from dynamic to static after colliding with another body. At the moment I’ve got:

```
-(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair static:(CCNode *)nodeA wildcard:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
   _player.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
}
```

or

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair static:(CCNode *)nodeA wildcard:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
   _player.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
   return YES;
}
```

but neither works. I get the error:

Aborting due to Chipmunk error: This operation cannot be done safely during a call to cpSpaceStep() or during a query. Put these calls into a post-step callback.
Failed condition: !space->locked

I then tried to make a joint at the point of collision but it doesn’t work right.

Is there a way to change a body to dynamic as soon as it collides in v3? I can do it in later versions using Box2D. I want to stop gravity and other forces so it doesn’t move. I want to make it look like it stuck to a surface.

Read a little on post-step callbacks but i'm unfamiliar with how to use them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please solve my same problem. [This is the question link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87475/cocos2dx-physics-abort-when-changing-dynamic-physicbody-to-static)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, you need to implement a post-step callback.
To do this on Cocos2d 3.0 and with Objective Chipmunk you first need to import a new header file to access advanced chipmunk properties:

```
#import "CCPhysics+ObjectiveChipmunk.h"
```

Then add the callback in your collision handler:

```
-(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair static:(CCNode *)nodeA wildcard:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    [[_physicsNode space] addPostStepBlock:^{
        _player.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
    } key:_player];
}
```

**Note that I assume you have access to your CCPhysicsNode in `_physicsNode`.**
The Chipmunk Space of `CCPhysicsNode`is locked while the a physics step is calculated. During a calculation of a step collisions are resolved and objects are moved around - changing the body type during this calculation could result in unexpected behaviour.

Therefore you add the `postStepBlock`callback. This is a place where a body type can be safely changed.

The `key` value you pass into the callback is used to ensure that the code is only called once (especially useful when removing objects, but it also makes sense in this case).

If also added an example implementation: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/367/make-a-dynamic-body-static-in-cocos2d-30-with-chi

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tried the code and it works. Although because of the wildcard I needed an if statement. 

If i put the if statement within the post-step callback it takes ages to output to console and calculate what's inside but if the callback is within the if statement everything's fine.

Also thank you for the explanation. While searching I could only find bits of info.

Comment: You're welcome!

Instead of using a wildcard you can also define a `collisionType` for the second colliding object.
You might also want to accept my answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: haha didn't think of that. anyways answer accepted and thanks again.

Comment: @Ben-G How about cocos2d-x v3.x. I face same error when `contact.getShapeA()->getBody()->setDynamic(false);` in `onContactPostSolve` event. What shoudl I do now ?

Comment: @Ben-G Can you please solve my same problem. [This is the question link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87475/cocos2dx-physics-abort-when-changing-dynamic-physicbody-to-static)