# How to apply impulse after an object collide another? [Chipmunk]

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, spritebuilder

I'm working on a game (with Cocos2d 3.0 and SpriteBuilder) in which a character smash another and gain impulse. To do this I'm trying the following:

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair hero:(CCNode *)hero goal:(CCNode *)goal {
    [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0.0f, 9000)];
    return TRUE;
}
```

And also:

```
-(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair hero:(CCNode *)hero goal:(CCNode *)goal {
    [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0.0f, 9000)];
}
```

But when the collision method is called, the character doesn't receive the impulse always. I also tried including the following inside "PostSolve" ([How to make a dynamic body static in Cocos2d v3.0 with Chipmunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593519/how-to-make-a-dynamic-body-static-in-cocos2d-v3-0-with-chipmunk)):

```
[[_physicsNode space] addPostStepBlock:^{
        [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0.0f, 9000)];
    } key:hero];
```

...but I have the same result. Do you hace any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There  was a rather embarrassing copy paste bug in apply impulse in v3 rc1. It's fixed in RC2 though.

Comment: Actually I'm using RC2. I also included the latest changes from Github: `-(void)applyImpulse:(CGPoint)impulse {_body.velocity = cpvadd(_body.velocity, cpvmult(CCP_TO_CPV(impulse), 1.0f/_body.mass));}`

Comment: OK @slembcke this is really strange. I replaced CCPhysicsBody, CCPhysicsNode and CCPhysics+ObjectiveChipmunk with the GitHub version and everything works fine in the emulator, but doesn't work with an iPhone 5.